# issue fetching PHAssets from PHAssetCollection using PHFetchOptions.predicate

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I'm trying to fetch images only from an PHAssetCollection but I don't see that the predicate is affecting the result.
I'm setting up the PHFetchOptions to mediaType == Image but when I select a video from the library it passes the predicate and the println confirms that type as well.

Not sure why this is happening, any issue I might be missing here ?

```
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", argumentArray: [PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue])
        println(fetchOptions) // mediaType == 1

        let assetsFetch = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(assetCollection, options: fetchOptions)

        assetsFetch.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (obj:AnyObject!, idx:Int, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
            if let asset = obj as? PHAsset{
                println(asset) 
                //prints: <PHAsset: 0x1703a1f80> A45796D5-528F-4D5E-A8D8-5F3F47CF40A1/L0/001 mediaType=2/0, assetSource=3, (1920x1080), creationDate=2014-11-11 16:34:12 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch and the options look good. Has the `PHAssetCollection` been created with `transientAssetCollectionWithAssets:title:` or `transientAssetCollectionWithAssetFetchResult:title`?

If that's the case, then the options are basically getting ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an option that does the job:

```
func convertFetchResultToPhotosArray(assetsFetch: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>) -> [PHAsset] {
    var photos = [PHAsset]()

    for i in 0 ..< assetsFetch.count {
        let asset = assetsFetch[i]
        if asset.mediaType == .image { photos.append(asset) }
    }

    return photos
}
```

... and then just pass your `assetsFetch` to this function